# Union all not working

Tags: sql, hive, union-all

I am trying to sum up the counts from 2 inner queries in Hive, but this throws the error "Not yet supported place for UDAF count". Any suggestions would be great

```
SELECT sum(count(distinct session),count(distinct session1)) FROM (
select concat(high, low, visit_num) as session from tab1
union all
select concat(high, low, visit_num) as session1 from tab2)t;
```

Comment: What is that supposed to do? `sum(count(distinct session),count(distinct session1))`

Comment: @juergend: I am trying to count the sum of distinct session and session1

Comment: Are you expecting two values back or one? In your union all, you are putting "session" and "session1" in the same column, but in your outer select you seem to be expecting them in two separate columns.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT sum(cnt) 
FROM 
(
  select count(distinct concat(high, low, visit_num)) as cnt from tab1
  union all
  select count(distinct concat(high, low, visit_num)) as cnt from tab2
) t
```

Comment: this will throw an error in Hive..use an alias in the second part of `union all` as well

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks